# C++ Calculate Angle (0 to 360) Between Two 3D Vectors

Tags: c++, math, 3d, trigonometry, angle

Let's say I have 2 3D Vectors

```
Vec3 v1, v2;

v1.x = 203;
v1.y = 355;
v1.z = 922;

v2.x = 6;
v2.y = 13;
v2.z = 198;
```

How would I calculate the angle between `v1` & `v2`? I.e. the final answer would be within `0` to `360`

I've tried

```
Vec3 angle = v1 - v2;
```

And a few other things but I just can't seem to get it working correctly.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974178/how-to-calculate-the-angle-between-2-vectors-in-3d-space-given-a-preset-function

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My question is not answered there

Comment: All you need to do is figure out what math functions C++ has.  I seem to recall there being a `math.h` header file.

Comment: Are you unsure of the math to compute the angle, or are you unsure of how to translate the math to code?

Comment: How did you eventually solve it? I'm interested as I have the very same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [dot product](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors-dot-product.html) for this, and once you have that you can follow the [standard method](http://onlinemschool.com/math/library/vector/angl/).
Example:

```
#include <cmath>

float dot(Vec3 a, Vec3 b)  //calculates dot product of a and b
{
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y + a.z * b.z;
}

float mag(Vec3 a)  //calculates magnitude of a
{
    return std::sqrt(a.x * a.x + a.y * a.y + a.z * a.z);
}

int main()
{
    Vec3 v1, v2;

    v1.x = 203;
    v1.y = 355;
    v1.z = 922;

    v2.x = 6;
    v2.y = 13;
    v2.z = 198;

    float angle = std::acos(dot(v1,v2)/(mag(v1)*mag(v2)));
}
```

Comment: @mireazma what do you expect would happen?

Comment: I don't understand your question. After reading your solution I expect it to return an angle between 0 and 180 degrees. But before reading it I was expecting your answer to return an angle between 0 and 360. What is the correct expectation?

Comment: @mireazma vectors don't have a fixed orientation, it s relative to the vector, and as such you can't have an angle larger than 180 degrees. You will always get the smallest angle, 30 would be the same as 330. Remember that the dot product could return either of two opposite facing vectors depending on which direction is defined positive. If you use a plane, and say that both vectors lie on said plane, you can use that planes normal as your constant positive direction, which would give you results ranging tom 360 degrees. You would just need to find the determinant of that plane.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wonder whether it's possible (hopefully) by first using a cross product and keeping track of the vectors order. If not, I think it would be theoretically possible by using quaternions, *only* in the case of 2 3D vectors.